# SharePoint Approval

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, workflow

I need to add sharepoint approval to a list... and I was hoping to use the default approval process... but...  I need to run some code once an item is approved.  Do I have to then use VS to create a custom workflow?

I need to run some code that currently runs in an event reciever.  I need to move the code to another function (as we are moving the processing out of event reciever code and now based on item approval).  This code would execute after the item is approved and can be hosted as a service or .net code.

Comment: so did you create custom workflow? if yes - was it completely new or maybe somehow based on approval workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full commented source to a state-machine based approval workflow comes with the MOSS SDK 1.5 in the samples directory.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6D94E307-67D9-41AC-B2D6-0074D6286FA9

-Oisin

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but close enough.  I really just needed to know if I had to create a custom workflow... or if there was a way to modify an OOB workflow (approval).  I believe I have to create a custom one.

Comment: the feature xml definition includes a lot of configurable options - you should examine it closer to see. The assoc/init forms also offer other tweaks.